# Convert a dfm to a dataframe

Tags: r, quanteda

Having the result of a dfm from quanteda:

```
library(quanteda); 
df <- data.frame(id = c(1), text = c("I am loving it"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

myDfm <- df$text %>%
    tokens(remove_punct = TRUE, remove_numbers = TRUE, remove_symbols = TRUE) %>%
    tokens_remove(pattern = c(stopwords(source = "smart"))) %>%
    dfm()
```

How is it possible to make the myDfm a dataframe which will have the number of rows and columns as the input but in text column it will have the clean text of the dfm process?

Example of expected output:

```
data.frame(id = c(1), text = c("loving"))
```

What I tried:

```
convert(myDfm, to = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Could you please provide as an example what you're expecting the output to be? This could help you find the answer sooner.

Comment: @ErrorJordan yes please check it in the update. It is what remain after the clean process

Comment: What would be your expected outcome if the result of the dfm contains more than 1 word for id 1? And you don't need the counts?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "a dataframe which will have the number of rows and columns as the input but in text column it will have the clean text of the dfm process?" Number of rows and columns of what? And what do you mean by the "clean text of the dfm process" - the feature name?

Answer (score 1):

A bit convoluted but the code below does the trick.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(quanteda)

out <- convert(myDfm, to = "data.frame")
pivot_longer(out, cols = !contains("document"), names_to = "features", values_to = "count")  %>% 
  mutate(id = as.integer(gsub("[a-z]", "", document))) %>% 
  inner_join(df) %>% # joins on id
  select(id, features) # select only the id and features column

Joining, by = "id"
# A tibble: 1 x 2
     id features
  <dbl> <chr>   
1     1 loving
```

The first 2 lines of the code could be replaced by `tidytext::tidy`

Now if the result is more than one word, you could use summerize to collapes them into 1 line.

Example based on 2 records to remove unwanted values:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1,2), text = c("I am loving it", "I am hating it"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

myDfm <- df$text %>%
  tokens(remove_punct = TRUE, remove_numbers = TRUE, remove_symbols = TRUE) %>%
  tokens_remove(pattern = c(stopwords(source = "smart"))) %>%
  dfm()

out <- convert(myDfm, to = "data.frame")
pivot_longer(out, cols = !contains("document"), names_to = "features", values_to = "count")  %>% 
  mutate(id = as.integer(gsub("[a-z]", "", document))) %>% 
  filter(count != 0) %>% 
  inner_join(df) %>% # joins on id
  select(id, features) # select only the id and features column

Joining, by = "id"
# A tibble: 2 x 2
     id features
  <dbl> <chr>   
1     1 loving  
2     2 hating
```

Comment: `Error: `!contains("document")` must evaluate to column positions or names, not a logical vector
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.` thank I receive this error when I run it

Comment: @Nathalie, based on your example the code runs fine on my machine. You might want to add a `filter(count != 0)` after the mutate statement to filter out the 0 values. I added an example to the answer.

Comment: thank you. I checked the update but again the same error

Comment: @Nathalie, What happens when you update tidyr (and tidyselect)? There where some changes in these packages with the last updates. I run R 4.0, and the latest packages of quanteda, dplyr, tidyr, tidyselect, etc.